# Gnome doesn't work in new kernel (Fedora16)

Tags: gnome, boot

I'm using Fedora 16. The kernel version is

> 3.6.7-4.fc16.x86_64

where GNOME graphics works fine and I have also installed the Nvidia graphics driver.
When I update yum then new kernel

> 3.6.10-2.fc16.x86_64

has been updated. When I select this kernel loading window occurs but after loading gnome graphical window doesn't open. Why?

Comment: GNOME, or X? That's a pretty big difference.

Comment: @Michael It is GNOME

Answer (score 4):

If you use the propietary nVidia driver, you have to rebuild it for the new kernel. And nVidia frequently lags behind (*way* behind) Fedora's kernel and graphics stack. As this is closed source, only nVidia can fix that.

Note that Fedora 16 went end-of-life a month or so ago, upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to vonbrand's answer, and seemingly not what you experienced, but certainly what I experienced, NVIDIA's proprietary drivers prior to release 310.40 (and beta drivers 313.09 and earlier) were hard-coded to check for kernel versions and only worked for kernels prior to 3.7.6.

To use the proprietary drivers with kernel 3.7.6 or later, even with a rebuild, one either had to modify the source to the driver ([not difficult](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/528955/nvidia-linux-x86_64-310-32-and-kernel-3-7-6/)) or use a newer driver ([310.40 works](http://www.geforce.com/drivers)).